# Javascript gives wrong result for 0.6 / 0.2 = 2.9999999999999996 instead of 3

Tags: javascript

Why 'divide' arithmetic calcualtion for **0.6 / 0.2 = 2.9999999999999996** gives javascript function, instead of 3

Comment: [Welcome to the world of floats](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 3):

Because in binary, `0.6` is not exactly `0.6`, and `0.2` is not exactly `0.2`.

"Not exactly 0.6" / "Not exactly 0.2" = "Not exactly 3"

---

In computers, all numbers are represented in binary. When you write `0.6`, the computer actually stores...

```
1/2 + 1/16 + 1/32 + 1/256 + ...
```

Similarly for `0.2`:

```
1/8 + 1/16 + 1/128 + 1/256 + ...
```

Consequently, you get a result along the lines of diving all those items, which comes out to something that is almost, but not quite, entirely unlike `3`.

Consider working with integers only if possible.

---

Further edit: You can actually observe this in the browser's console.

[image: console]

You see? the result of the division is extremely close to, but not exactly the expected answer.